Removing Intermediate forms using Integration
As we know that using L'hospital rule rule we can differentiate the numerator and denominator separately to remove the Intermediate form.
For example $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{e^x-1}{x^2+x}}$$
So my doubt is why can't we integrate to remove the Intermediate forms in specifically Limits based problems.
